# Application compiled with VS2013 wants VS2005 runtime

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have environment where both VisualStudio 2005 and VisualStudio 2013 are installed. And I have strange situation with some of the projects. I compile such projects with VS2013 and when I try to launch them through Explorer or command line I get an error - "The program can't start because MSVCR80.dll is missing ...". Why msvcr80 when I compile with msvcr120?

What I tried:

1. Put msvc*80.dll to directory with executable. I got runtime error "R6034. An application has made an attempt to load the C runtime library incorrectly..."
2. Checked binary dependencies with Dependency Walker. I saw that binary has dependencies to VS2013 runtime, and there is no mention about msvcr80.dll
3. Launched binary with empty PATH. I gave no positive effect.
4. Launched binary on another 'clean' pc. And it worked all right with vs2013 runtime.

How can this be?

Comment: Is there an indirect dependency via some other DLL?

Comment: I didn't see it through Dependcy Walker

Comment: Using google, it seems to say that DLL is also used by Office 2010.  So depending on what your app does there may be an indirect dependency.

Comment: Yury, Sebastian is correct, I had same problem a while ago. You will see the dependency only when you fix your environment. It is some other library that triggers it.

Comment: But why binary works on "clean" pc and doesn't work on my pc with empty path (set path=.)? I think if I have one exe in dir and empty PATH, then no one external dll will be loaded.

Comment: Windows has default locations that would be checked for libraries aka system32. If you have a clean pc where it works try to run dependency walker there on your binary,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all, you was right. I just forgot, that I have installed old version of my product. It was launched in background and used old versions of libraries. So when I ran my new application it tried to use libraries that already had beed loaded. In another way Dependecy walker didn't check already loaded libraries and looked only in PATH.

MSDN link about DLL loading - https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I have the same problem with visual studio 2017 project, and it compiles ok, but when running, at start up needs msvcrt90.dll,  I've put msvcrt90.dll beside project .cpp files and get exact same R6034 error like you. Would you give me some guid?